# Calling drawing commands externally in Processing

Tags: user-interface, event-handling, processing

I am trying to use g4p-controls library in Processing to create a button that executes a drawing command in another window. In this library, a child window is created by the code

```java
GWindow window = GWindow.getWindow(this, "Main", 100, 50, 500, 500, JAVA2D);
```

where `this` is the main applet, and the other arguments specify the name, position, and renderer.
GWindow is a subclass of PApplet, so I should feasibly be able to call a drawing command, for example `window.background(0);`, from anywhere in my code to paint that window black. However, this does not work, and I cannot figure out why. After all, the same code works when I put it in a handler function and add it to the window:

```java
window.addDrawHandler(this, "windowDraw");
```

where the `windowDraw` method is

```java
public void windowDraw(PApplet app, GWinData data) {
  app.background(0);
}
```

Looking into the source code, the draw handler method `windowDraw` is invoked by the GWindow object with the first argument `this`, which is exactly the object referred to when I attempted `window.background(0);`. So `window` should be the object whose `background()` method is called to paint the canvas black.

If I am misunderstanding something fundamental about event-driven programming, please let me know. It does seem like the handlers take the relevant applet as an argument for a reason, but I really cannot see what's different about invocation inside and outside the handler functions.

Some additional notes: calling `window.background(0);` works if it's inside the main `draw()` function. It does not work if it's in the `setup()` function, and unfortunately for me, it doesn't work if it's in a button handler method:

```java
public void handleButtonEvents(GButton button, GEvent event) {
  if (this.button == button) {
    if (event == GEvent.PRESSED) {
      window.background(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, I have made sure this code actually runs when I press the button.

Even more strangely, if I substitute the above drawing call to `window` with something like `window.strokeWeight(10)`, the change actually takes place, and subsequent lines in that canvas are drawn thicker. It only fails to actually draw things. I am just at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a bunch of disconnected code snippets. Here's an example:

```java
import g4p_controls.*;

GWindow window;

void setup(){
  window = GWindow.getWindow(this, "Main", 100, 50, 500, 500, JAVA2D);
}

void draw(){
   background(255, 0, 0); 
   window.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
   window.draw();
}

void mousePressed(){
  window.background(0, 255, 0); 
}
```

I would expect this code to draw circles in the second window, and to draw green in the second window when I press the mouse in the first window. However, it seems to only draw those things very sporadically.

In fact, here's the same type of program, in "pure Processing" without using the G4P library:

```java
SecondApplet sa;

void setup() {
  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
}

void settings() {  
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  sa.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
}   

void mousePressed() {
  sa.background(255, 0, 0);
}

public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 200);
  }

  void draw() {
  }
}
```

I would also expect this to work, but we see a similar gray window for the second sketch. I've filed a bug [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5255) to get feedback from the Processing devs about whether this is expected behavior.

In the meantime, you'll have better luck if you do something like this:

```java
SecondApplet sa;

float drawMouseX;
float drawMouseY;
color drawBackground = #0000ff;

void setup() {
  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
}

void settings() {  
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  drawMouseX = mouseX;
  drawMouseY = mouseY;
}   

void mousePressed() {
  drawBackground = #00ff00;
}

public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 200);
  }

  void draw() {
    background(drawBackground);
    ellipse(drawMouseX, drawMouseY, 25, 25);
  }
}
```

Instead of calling the drawing functions directly, we're now setting some variables that are then used in the second applet's `draw()` function. There are a bunch of ways to do this, but the idea is the same: just don't call the draw functions directly, and call them from the `draw()` function instead.

**Update:** I heard back from Ben Fry (a founder of Processing) and codeanticode (a developer of Processing) on [the bug](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5255) I filed on GitHub, and I understand better now why this doesn't work.

**The reason it doesn't work** is because each sketch has its own UI thread, which is responsible for drawing and handling events. You can't draw to a sketch from a different thread, otherwise weird things happen. But you're trying to draw to a second sketch from the first sketche's event thread, which is **not** the second sketch's drawing thread, which is why it doesn't work.

See the bug for a discussion on alternative approaches, but honestly your best bet is probably to go with the approach I outlined of just sharing variables between the sketches.

Comment: Yes, using conditionals in the draw function is the workaround I am using for now. But I also want to perform a computationally expensive sequence of thousands of drawing commands upon an external trigger, and this solution is not very conducive to ensuring that it only happens once.

Comment: @ShnitzelKiller You might also use a `PGraphics` buffer. Or the `noLoop()` function might come in handy.

Comment: @ShnitzelKiller Please see the update I just added to my answer.